# Is it allowed to use a USB-C connector to a USB 2 host?

Tags: usb-c, usb-host, regulations

I am working on a product that is intended for at least the european market and possibly the US market as well.
I am not at all acquainted with the USB specifications, and currently I do not intend to become that if not necessary. I just want something that works, and that will not get me in some legal trouble :)

**TLDR**
Can I get in legal trouble for not following the USB-C specification? (fixed 5 V without current negotiation and only D+ D- routed)

So, my project contains a USB 2.0 host (a linux module). I want to route this to a good old USB Type A Female connector, but it is way too big for this application. The USB-C connector is a better fit, and I like that it feels sturdy and is symmetrical, so I am thinking of using this.

I don't intend to support anything more than necessary. In my mind that includes the following:

- Routing the D+ and D- to the Linux module
- Routing the power to my PSU (no possibility to negotiate the current)
- Routing the USB-C connector symmetrically to support a flipped usb cable.
- (Maybe necessary to pull down CC1 and CC2 to ground with 5.1k resistor?)

Then I suppose I can use an off-the-shelf "USB-C OTG" adapter to connect my good old USB-A peripheral. The supported peripherals for my product will be very limited, probably to only a known USB-modem.

[image: Concept of my idea]

Native USB-C devices are not (necessarily) intended to work with this product.

From what I could find, I can violate the USB specification to my hearts content as long as I don't put the USB logo on my product.

Is this the case, or can I get in legal trouble for not fully supporting USB?

Comment: The only extra hardware you need is a switch on Vbus that is turned on when the CC pin is pulled low. This can just be a couple of transistors. The USB host doesn't even need to get involved, as any attached device won't start enumerating until it gets supplied with power. It's good practice to use a USB power switch anyway (even for USB A implementations) as these usually have over-current protection.

Comment: "Can I get in legal trouble for not following the USB-C specification?" - I would guess no, as long you do not use their Logo or right protected terms... Maybe just name it USB 2.0 compatible or so... Well I own at least one USB 2.0 device with a USB-C Connector, why should it be not allowed at a host?